# Start GitLog with Java Process Builder

Tags: java, processbuilder, git-log

I try to start a GitLog command via Processbuilder in Java.

GitLog Command :

> git --git-dir=C:/Users/User/Code/code1/git/.git log
>   --pretty=format:"%H \"%an\" %ad \"%s\"" --numstat --date=short

This is my code. The Path is the path to the git dir. 
I hardcoded the gitpath to the git dir for testing.

```
public void createGitLog( Path path ) {
            try
            {          
                String gitpath = "--git-dir=C:/Users/User/Code/code1/git/.git";
                String options = "--pretty=format:\"%H \\\"%an\\\" %ad \\\"%s\\\"\" --numstat --date=short";

                ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("git", gitpath, "log", options );
                Process process = builder.start();

                builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.to( path.resolve("gitlog.dat").toFile() ) );

                int exitValue = process.waitFor();

                if ( exitValue != 0 )
                {
                    // throw
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {

            } 
}
```

If i try this command in the cmd it works, but in Java I get always the exitcode 128.

What is the Problem with this process ?

Comment: when you run it via command line you probably use some saved settings like password, ssh key. try running another command (e.g.  to save credentials) in your code to ensure git can run smoothly.

Comment: did you solve your case im facing the same error with the same command in linux 
@Drextor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That what works in my case to run commands in terminal:

> "/bin/bash" - path to your bash
>
> "-c" - states that next param is command
>
> "command" - full command you want to execute from terminal (like `git log --pretty=format:"%H \"%an\" %ad \"%s\"" --numstat --date=short`)

```
String command = "git " + gitpath + " log " + options;
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash" , "-c" , command);
```

you can also use on ProcessBuilder `directory()` if you want to start process from specific dir;

```
 .directory(new File("C:/Users/User/Code/code1/git/"))
```