# Java ProcessBuilder returns exit error 128 executing git in linux ( some git command working fine )

Tags: java, linux, git, processbuilder

Simple git command i try to execute with java ProcessBuilder , working find when i run it in linux with results returned. 
this is the command :

```
git -C /home/mlxx log -1 "72xxxxxxxxe700d6bbe06" --pretty=format:"%s"
```

when i try to execute it in java

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder()
                    .command("git","-C","/home/mlxx","log","1","72xxxxxxxxe700d6bbe06","--pretty=format:\"%s\"").directory("/bin/bash");
```

The int exit = p.waitFor(); returns 128 error code

now according to this link :
[Start GitLog with Java Process Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407664/start-gitlog-with-java-process-builder)
which face the same problem

i tried to do :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder()
                        .command("/usr/bin","-c""git","-C","/home/mlxx","log","1","72xxxxxxxxe700d6bbe06","--pretty=format:\"%s\"")
```

The int exit = p.waitFor(); returns 1 error c0de

what is wrong here ?

other commands working just fine in linux via java?

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying `/bin/bash` as the process's working directory:

```
[...] .directory("/bin/bash");
```

This is an executable file and not a valid directory.

You can leave it off entirely, since you already specify the directory `git` should operate on with its `-C` option.

Comment: it was stype mistake i fixed it to /usr/bin
but i wtill have the erro